# Swift: How to check if a certain button pressed inside function?

Tags: uibutton, swift3, ibaction

I am new to Swift and Xcode and having some problems with checking whether certain button is pressed or not inside a function. Seems I can not just use isTouchInside here and was wondering if there is another way of doing it. Should I create another button action with tags and use it in my current function or is there an easier way to solve it?

```
    func nextQuestion1(){
    TextView.text = "Choose word Yellow"
    stackView.isHidden = false
    playBtn.isHidden = true

    if btn1.isTouchInside {
        mondaiNumber.isHidden = false

    }
    else {
        mondaiNumber.isHidden = true
    }

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 3
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        self.nextQuestion2()

}
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isTouchInside` works only if you are tracking touches.  You should start tracking using

```
func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

To check in button is tracking touches use `isTracking`:

```
button.isTracking
```